# Выполнить функцию при нажатии на кнопку ReplyKeyboardMarkup (то бишь при отправке боту определенного сообщения)

Tags: python-3.x, telegram-bot, telebot

При нажатии в меню кнопки "Про ЦЗО" должна выполняться функция about_czo. Как это реализовать?

```
@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def handle_start(message):
    markup_reply = telebot.types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(True, False)
    bt1 = types.KeyboardButton('Про ЦЗО')
    bt2 = types.KeyboardButton('Регламент взаємодії')
    bt3 = types.KeyboardButton("Зворотній зв'язок")
    markup_reply.add(bt1, bt2, bt3)
    msg = bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, 'Вітаю! Оберіть дію:', reply_markup=markup_reply)
    bot.register_next_step_handler(msg, get_text_messages)

def get_text_messages(message):
    if message.text == 'Про ЦЗО':
        bot.send_message(message.data.about_czo)
    elif message.text == 'Регламент взаємодії':
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, '12')
    elif message.text == "Зворотній зв'язок":
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, '123')

def about_czo(message):
    markup_inline = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
    item_normativdoc = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text="Нормативні документи", callback_data='normativdoc')
    item_aboutuss = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='Про нас', url='https://')

    markup_inline.add(item_normativdoc, item_aboutuss)
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Оберіть дію:',
                     reply_markup=markup_inline
                     )
```

Comment: ReplyKeyboardMarkup отправляет как текст, поэтому добавьте обработчик на `text`

Comment: Я совсем новичок в этом.
Можете ткнуть носом что именно и куда добавить?

Comment: https://github.com/eternnoir/pyTelegramBotAPI/blob/888c7a6b0d97c376947ee7b525d4b70583acc3fc/examples/echo_bot.py